# unit testing MVVMLight DispatcherHelper with Timer does not work

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, timer, mvvm-light

I have an application where I use System.Threading.Timer.  When Timer callback is called, I have to do something on UI thread.  I use MVVMLight DispatcherHelper to do it.  It works fine when I run application, but when I unit test it (using nUnit), the DispatcherHelper does not invoke the Action.

To demonstrate it, I create a simple unit test

```
Timer _Timer; //this is System.Threading.Timer
bool _DispatcherWorks;

[Test]
public async Task MVVMDispatcherTest()
{
     DispatcherHelper.Initialize();
     Assert.That(DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher, Is.Not.Null);

     _Timer = new Timer(timerCallback, null, 500, 500); //start timer in 0.5 seconds and run every 0.5 seconds

     Thread.Sleep(2000); //wait for timer to tick

     Assert.That(_DispatcherWorks, Is.True); //will fail
}

private void timerCallback(object state)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Timer tick");
     Assert.That(DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher, Is.Not.Null);
     DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() =>
     {
         _DispatcherWorks = true; //this is never called
     });
 }
```

My timer gets executed 3 times, which is expected.  But the Action inside DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvoikeOnUI does not get called.  Can anyone suggest why this is not working and how to make this testable?

Answer (score 0):

Your _Timer is an instance of System.Threading.Timer (call this instance timerA). In your Dispatchhelper a new instance of System.Threading.Timer is created (call that instance timerB). This should explain why your test does not work. 
In order to make this testable there are a few things you can do. You could inject the timer in your Dispatch-helper, but you would have to change your productioncode to accomodate tests. This I am usually opposed to if it can be helped.

You could also use Microsoft Fakes to mock the System.Threading.Timer. This is the approach I would take.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggest, but it would not work for me because I actually want to test what is happening inside the timer event when it elapses.  So here what I did.

1. I took source code from MVVMLight DispatcherHelper.cs, converted this class from static to non-static class and extracted Interface from it.  I pass Dispatcher as a parameter into constructor.  In my ViewModelLocator, I initiate my new DispatcherHelper class.
2. I pass the same DispatcherHelper object which I initiated in ViewModelLocator to a constructor for each of my ViewModels where I would need a Dispatcher.  Then I use this object in the timer elapsed event.
3. In my unit test, I use nSubstitute to mock the IDispatcherHelper interface and redefined the CheckBeginInvokeOnUI method to simply execute the passed action instead of using Dispatcher.
4. Now, when I test my ViewModel, I pass this mocked DispatcherHelper into the ViewModel constructor and I am able to test what happens inside the timer.